# How to reduce number of hierarchical 'if statements'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, erb

I have hierarchical the statements like this

```
<% @descriptions.each_with_index do |description, i| %>
  <% description.tale2.each do |tax_ref| %>            
    <% if condition %>              
      <% if condition %>
        <% if condition %>                  
          <%= $text_first_describe%> <%= $paren_author_yr %>
             <% ref_sp_uniq.each_with_index do |ref, i| %>
               <% if ref == tax_ref.ref_wo_brace%>
                  <% execution %>                      
               <% elsif i == (ref_sp_uniq.size - 1)%>
                  <%# @ref_desc = "#{@ref_desc_numb}. #{tax_ref.ref_wo_brace}" %>
               <% end %>
             <% end %>
          <% if condition %>
                  <% execution %>                      
          <% elsif condition %>
            <% execution %>
          <% elsif taxon_name.emend_author_year %>                    
             <%= print %>
          <% else %>                    
             <%= print %>                    
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% else %>
        <% if condition %>
          <%= print %>
          <% ref_sp_uniq.each_with_index do |ref, i| %>
             <% if condition %>
                <% execution %>                      
             <% elsif condition %>
                  <% execution %>                      
             <% end %>
          <% end %>
          <% if condition %>
            <% execution %>                      
          <% elsif condition %>
            <% execution %>                      
          <% elsif condition %>
            <% execution %>                      
          <% else %>
            <% execution %>                      
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>        
<% end %>
```

Kindly suggest me possible way to reduce this kind of junk "if statements".

Comment: if's are not loops. I guess you mean "if statements".

Comment: I don't know what the conditions are, but perhaps rethinking them could help, joining them with "and"s and "or"s, parenthesis, etc. Doing so might not help readability though.

Comment: @martinho: Apologize, for mentioned as if loops its "if statement"

Comment: @lan: I cant include everything in single condition using 'and' because, its hierarchal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all I would put this code in a helper, so you get rid of all the tags and you clean the view, then look if you can apply the `case` statement and latter remember maybe you can include `line_of_code if condition` or `condition ? code_a : code_b`.

Hard to do something without conditions (I suppose the condition change each if), why not to address the question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
?

Answer (score 4):

If your nested IFs are becoming very complex, you might consider describing the entire structure with a state machine and processing it like that.  That way you get the documentation of the formal state diagram and your code will be much simpler.

Edit:

Here is a better attempt to describe the process.  The nice thing about
this is that once you have your initial state diagram and the code to
process it, adding new states is very easy to do.  (Expecially if you
build a little tool to read your diagram and generate your table for
you).

Most people just use these in the context of regular expressions and
leave them alone otherwise, but it is a nice powerful tool to have in
your toolbox.  A common example is implementing a full ftp server this
way is trivially easy.

Ok, to my better example, hope this helps.

Consider this IF psuedo code:

```
if (a < 5)
  do_b
  do_c
  if (a < 3)
    do_d
  else
    do_e
  end-if
end-if
```

The state transition table to process this might look like:

```
State   Transition  Action   Next state  
-----   ----------  ------   -----   
1       a < 5                2          
1                            7
2                   do_b     3
3                   do_c     4
4       a < 3                5
4                            6
5                   do_d     7
6                   do_e     7
7                   exit
```

The code to process it would look like this:

```
currentState = 1
foreach table entry
  if table_state == currentState 
    && table_transition is true or blank
       call table_action
       currentState = table_next_state
```

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_transition_table for a
more formal description.

Comment: sorry I don't understand, do you mean an external program that creates the ruby for that? could you give an example, sounds interesting...

Comment: No, I mean document your deeply nested IFs in a state machine style of bubble & arrows.  The bubbles are states, which correspond to the body of your IFs and ELSEs.  The arrows are the transitions that occur depending upon the current state and variable values.  To process it, you start at the beginning and take the first valid transition you find, perform the operations in that state and loop again until you come to an exit state.

Comment: It sounds harder than it is.  Much easier to describe with a white board and markers than in text.

Comment: Interesting approach, it would be nice to illustrate a construction of such a table based on some real life scenarios. Consider an `bool IsAuthorized() ` method versus a `void Mutate(ComplexObject obj)` or even `void DoWork()`. The last 2 seem to be harder to comprehend in terms of 'state' definition. I like ideea but an algorithm of table construction should be defined as well :)

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby's case syntax](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/) would probably be a good starting point for cleaning that up, but like others have mentioned you probably need to rethink whats going on in there. Ultimately you probably want to be moving as much of that logic into the model as you can.

My two cents.